# Does jQuery have the equivalent of Dojo's enhanced <select>?

Tags: jquery, dojo

Dojo has this:
http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-0.4.3/dojo-0.4.3-widget/tests/widget/test_Select.html

Similar to Google Auto-suggest.

Does jQuery have anything similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, jQuery has an [AutoComplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) plugin